# Android - Parse error [Nexus 9 tablet and Nexus 6p]

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, android-6.0-marshmallow, parse-error

When I am trying to run my app on **Nexus 9 tablet and Nexus 6p**, I am facing the **parse error - There was a problem parsing the package**, but its run properly on Nexus 4 and few more devices which is not on **marshmallow**.

I am not understand what i am missing, my gradle file code is below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

[image]